# Utilizar uma função com temporizador para criar várias bolas animadas

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Olá,

Estou a aprender JavaScript e gostaria de saber como posso criar várias bolas animadas. Pensei em criar esta função para não ter de repetir o código para todas as bolas:

```
            const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

            balls = (color, x, y, dx, dy) => {

                setInterval (() => {

                    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
                    canvas.fillStyle = color;
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    canvas.fill();

                    if (x >= 600 || x <= 0) {
                        dx = -dx;
                    }

                    if (y >= 600 || y <= 0) {
                        dy = -dy;
                    }

                    x = x + dx;
                    y = y + dy;

                }, 20);
            }

            balls("#00f", 35, 35, 5, 5);

            balls("#f00", 400, 35, 5, 5);
```

No entanto não está a funcionar corretamente, pois só a segunda bola surge no ecrã, enquanto que a primeira fica a piscar em intervalos.

O que estou a fazer de errado? Alguém me consegue ajudar? Obrigado.